# how to print a list of dicts python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

i have a list of dicts with and for each key i have more values

```
tournament = [{
'nome_file': 'Blue Moon',
'torneo': ['Rimnimi', 'Padova'],
'win': ['3', '4'], 
'lose': ['4', '3'], 
'tie': ['1', '1'], 
'posizione': ['6', '7']
}, 
{'nome_file': 'Phoenix', 
'torneo': ['Madrid', 'Magifest', 'Gp Lione'],
'win': ['1', '4', '5'], 
'lose': ['6', '3', '4'], 
'tie': ['7', '1', '3'], 
'posizione': ['3', '2', '5']
}]
```

and i want iterate to them for have an output like this

```
Blue Moon
torneo : Rimnimi, win-lose-tie: 3-4-1, posizione 6
torneo : Padova, win-lose-tie: 4-3-1, posizione 7
Phoenix
torneo : Madrid, win-lose-tie: 1-6-7, posizione 3
torneo : Magicfest, win-lose-tie: 4-3-1, posizione 2
torneo : Gp Lione, win-lose-tie: 5-4-1, posizione 5
```

Comment: Okay, show us what you've tried so far and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `zip` the lists together:

```
for t in tournament:
    print(t['nome_file'])
    zipped = zip(t['torneo'], t['win'], t['lose'], t['tie'], t['posizione'])
    for torneo, win, lose, tie, posizione in zipped:
        print(f"torneo : {torneo}, win-lose-tie: {win}-{lose}-{tie}, posizione {posizione}")
```